# Create a table automatically depends upon the data from the database

Tags: php, sql

Hello I have a sample set of data in my database:

```
+-----------+-------------+---------------+-------+
| IDNumber  | SubjectCode | SubjectName   | Grade |
+-----------+-------------+---------------+-------+
| 2012-1234 | IT-101      | Intro to I.T  | 1.75  |
| 2012-1234 | IT-202      | Advanced I.T  | 1.50  |
| 2012-5678 | CS-300      | Haskell Prog. | 1.00  |
+-----------+-------------+---------------+-------+
```

My problem is how can I automatically create a table in PHP base on their data. Let's say when I want to search for IDNumber 2012-1234 it will create 4 column and 2 rows automatically and print it in the browswer, the same with IDNumber 2012-5678.

Just give me some hint and I'll just do the rest. Some help / ideas will be much more appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried googling for this at all?

Comment: If you make a `SELECT` query against that table, you'll have a "table" (2D array with data) which you can then use to produce result table. Useful function: `array_keys()` - for table headers.

Comment: What code have you written so far? Please post it and point out where you're stuck so we can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM table");
$names_fetched = false;
$row_names = [];
while ($row = $result->fetchAssoc()) {
  if (!$names_fetched) {
     $row_names = array_keys($result); //row titles are here
     $names_fecthed = true;
  }
  //other staff
}
```

Comment: Hello, I haven't tried to implement OOP in my project. It's just a basic one. Can you guide me what's the idea of this code. Tnx

Comment: there is no OOP at all, basic idea to fetch result rows ad associative    array.

Comment: Tnx. I'll just try to implement this code in my project.